# append data and write comment the comment repeated

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem

When added 3 posts and write a comment on the Post number 2 comment repeated.

Clarify more

when i added 3 posts

post 1 = a

post 2 = b

post 3 = c

and write a comment on post 2 this comment repeated pleas help

like this [photo](http://www12.0zz0.com/2013/07/14/14/357256498.jpg)

this is the file

index.php

```
<? include("../post/includes/config.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $("#update_state").submit(function(){
            var text = $(".text") .val();
            var s = {
              "text":text
            }
            $.ajax({
              url:'action.php',
              type:'POST',
              data:s,
              cache: false,
              beforeSend: function (){
                $(".loading") .show();
                $(".loading") .html("loading...");
              },
              success:function(html){
                $("#show_new_posts") .prepend(html);
                $(".loading") .hide();
                $(".text") .val("");
              }
            });
          return false;
          });

          //add comment

          $(".comment_form").submit(function(){
            var id_post = $(this).attr('rel');
            var text_comm  = $(".commtext[rel="+id_post+"]") .val();
            var s = {
              "id_post":id_post,
              "text_comm":text_comm
            }
            $.ajax({
              url:'add_comment.php',
              type:'post',
              data:s,
              beforeSend: function (){
                $(".loadingcomm[rel="+id_post+"]") .show();
                $(".loadingcomm[rel="+id_post+"]") .html("<img src=\"style/img/ajax/load1.gif\" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
              },
              success:function(html){
                $(".loadingcomm[rel="+id_post+"]").hide();
                $(".commtext[rel="+id_post+"]") .val("");
                $(".shownewcomm[rel="+id_post+"]").append(html);
              }
            });
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="update_state">
      <textarea class="text" name="text"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="go" />
    </form>
    <div class="loading"></div>
    <div id="show_new_posts"></div>
<?
$select_posts = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT  4 ");
$num_posts = $select_posts->num_rows;
if($num_posts){
  while ($rows_posts = $select_posts->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $id_posts             = $rows_posts ['id'];
    $post_posts           = $rows_posts ['post'];
?>
<div style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background:#ccc; width:300px;">
  <b>admin</b>
</div>
<div style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background:#ccc; width:300px;">
  <? echo $post_posts; ?>
</div>
<div class="shownewcomm" rel="<? echo $id_posts; ?>"></div>
<form rel="<? echo $id_posts; ?>" class="comment_form">
  <textarea rel="<? echo $id_posts; ?>" style="height: 20px;" placeholder="Comment.." class="commtext"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="comment" />
</form>
<hr />
<?
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    $(".comment_form").submit(function(){

      var id_post = $(this).attr('rel');
      var text_comm  = $(".commtext[rel="+id_post+"]") .val();

      var s = {
        "id_post":id_post,
        "text_comm":text_comm
      }

      $.ajax({
        url:'add_comment.php',
        type:'post',
        data:s,
        beforeSend: function (){
          $(".loadingcomm[rel="+id_post+"]") .show();
          $(".loadingcomm[rel="+id_post+"]") .html("<img src=\"style/img/ajax/load1.gif\" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
        },
        success:function(html){
          $(".loadingcomm[rel="+id_post+"]").hide();
          $(".commtext[rel="+id_post+"]") .val("");
          $(".shownewcomm[rel="+id_post+"]").append(html);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

  });
</script>


<?php
include("../post/includes/config.php");
$text = $_POST['text'];

$insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO posts (id, post) VALUE ('', '$text')");
$id_posts = $mysqli->insert_id;
if($insert){
  ?>
<div style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background:#ccc; width:300px;">
  <b>admin</b>
</div>
<div style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background:#ccc; width:300px;">
  <? echo $text; ?>
</div>
<div class="shownewcomm" rel="<? echo $id_posts; ?>"></div>
<form rel="<? echo $id_posts; ?>" class="comment_form">
  <textarea rel="<? echo $id_posts; ?>" style="height: 20px;" placeholder="Comment.." class="commtext"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="comment" />
</form>
<hr />
<?
}
?>
```

add_comment.php

```
<?php
$id_post = $_POST['id_post'];
$text_comm = $_POST['text_comm'];

?>
admin :  <? echo $text_comm;  ?>
<br />
```

Comment: -1 After reading it a few times, I still have no clue what you are trying to say. I've added some indentation to your code (if the edit get's confirmed) so that your code is at least readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `$(".comment_form").submit` with `ajax call` in `index.php` and `action.php`. And in `index.php` you are prepending `action.php` result like this

```
$("#show_new_posts").prepend(html);
```

May be because of this there will be more than one `ajax call`. Remove all `JavaScript` code from `action.php` and try

Update:

Changes made in `action.php` are as below:

1. Removed jquery reference from it as already there in `index.php` and moved other `JS` code at the end
2. Added id in form

   `<form rel="<?php echo $id_posts; ?>" id="comment_form_<?php echo $id_posts; ?>" class="comment_form">`
3. Updated submit handler to use form id like this:

   `$("#comment_form_<?php echo $id_posts; ?>").submit(function(){`

Updated `action.php` code is as below:

```
<?php
include("../post/includes/config.php");
$text = $_POST['text'];

$insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO posts (id, post) VALUE ('', '$text')");
$id_posts = $mysqli->insert_id;
if ($insert) {
    ?>
    <div style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background:#ccc; width:300px;">
        <b>admin</b>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background:#ccc; width:300px;">
        <?php echo $text; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="shownewcomm" rel="<?php echo $id_posts; ?>"></div>
    <form rel="<?php echo $id_posts; ?>" id="comment_form_<?php echo $id_posts; ?>" class="comment_form">
        <textarea rel="<?php echo $id_posts; ?>" style="height: 20px;" placeholder="Comment.." class="commtext"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="comment" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#comment_form_<?php echo $id_posts; ?>").submit(function(){

                var id_post = $(this).attr('rel');
                var text_comm = $(".commtext[rel=" + id_post + "]").val();

                var s = {
                    "id_post": id_post,
                    "text_comm": text_comm
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'add_comment.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: s,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $(".loadingcomm[rel=" + id_post + "]").show();
                        $(".loadingcomm[rel=" + id_post + "]").html("<img src=\"style/img/ajax/load1.gif\" alt=\"Loading ....\" />");
                    },
                    success: function(html) {
                        $(".loadingcomm[rel=" + id_post + "]").hide();
                        $(".commtext[rel=" + id_post + "]").val("");
                        $(".shownewcomm[rel=" + id_post + "]").append(html);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```